# Universal click step in cucumber rails (with and without selenium)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I want to make a universal click step which I could call in scenarios with and without @javascript flag.

So far it is :

```
When(/^I click "([^"]*)"$/) do |clickable|
  click_on(clickable)
end
```

It is working fine, when It is not using WebDriver. But when I use WebDriver, it puts focus on the link or button, but does not click it.

If I simulate pressing "Enter" then it works fine with WebDriver, but raises an exception in Pure Capybara tests.

Is there a way to have one step which works with both?

UPDATE:

By putting `sleep 1` before click, I managed to get clicking on links working( highly doubt that it is efficient). I have no javascript or asynchronous loading in the page at this point. But clicking on button is still not working.

Comment: try `find_link(link_name).trigger(:click)`

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I want it to work with both- links and buttons

Comment: find(:link_or_button, locator).trigger(:click)

Comment: trigger function show to have been deprecated. And find does not work with values. only css selectors (as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

The code you show should work correctly both with and without selenium.  If it's not it generally means you have some JS code that is blocking the clicks, or with recent versions of selenium-webdriver that your elements may be hidden behind other elements (fixed header/footer bar for instance) - although that would normally show an error.

Assuming it's not failing on every click you attempt, then you need to look at the ones that are failing and see what common things are being done (maybe post some of the html) - Since you say a 1 second sleep fixes it, I would guess you have some fields being transformed by JS libraries and the clicks are being ignored until the libraries have finished transforming the elements.

Comment: I took out all javascript from the page and then the link worked. Though when I tried submitting form with the same step it did nothing(even with no javascript). It is weird though, that javascript was preventing from clicking on that link given that nothing in that page is referenced or done in javascript.

Comment: It sounds like you either have delegated listeners that are a little overzealous in which clicks they're grabbing, or possibly some errors in your JS that are preventing JS you think should be working from actually happening (remote form submission, etc) -  Adding some example html to your question would help

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try finding the element to be clicked using the css selector and then click on the element.

```
def click_element(selector)
  begin
    el = find(:css, selector)
  rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound => e
    puts "Element with Selector - #{selector} not found on the page"
    raise e
  end
  call_click el
end

def call_click (selector)
  if (IS_HEADLESS)
    selector.trigger('click')
  else
    selector.click
  end
end
```